# How to convert appsettings.json section to dynamic and then to class object in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I have an appsettings:

```
"testData": [
    {
      "target": "MarketMirrorClient.GetContests",
      "mockData": [
        {
          "request": {
            "contestKeys": [ "testContestKey1" ]
          },
          "response": {
            "contests": [
              {
                "contestKey": "testContestKey1",
                "contestType": "football",
                "contestStatus": "InPlay"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "request": {
            "contestKeys": [ "testContestKey2" ]
          },
          "response": {
            "contests": [
              {
                "contestKey": "testContestKey2",
                "contestType": "soccer",
                "contestStatus": "PreGame"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I serialize the `testData.mockData.request` to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. However, when I try to convert the retrieved object from the dictionary to a particular type, it throws an exception saying `IConvertible` needs to be implemented e.g.

```
builder.Services.Configure<MockTestData>("testData");
```

The models are:

```
public class MockTestData
{
    public List<TestData> TestData { get; set; } = new();
}

public class TestData
{
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public List<MockData> MockData { get; set; } = new();
}

public class MockData
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Request { get; set; }
    public object Response { get; set; }
}
```

Where should I implement the IConvertible?

I tried changing the types from object to dynamic or ExpandoObject but the error is either IConvertible needs to be implemented or Cannot convert object to 'whatever' type i am casting to i.e. List

Comment: Why would you want your `appsettings.json` to be cluttered with test data. It's not meant for this. However, in general, it is possible to do this using the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Stop thinking about configuration being JSON. It is not. It is set of key-value pairs which can be represented in JSON. Store data in some other files and load them when needed, do not use configs for that.

Comment: This is a typical ["XY problem"](https://xyproblem.info/). You are asking us to fix your solution to a problem instead of asking help with the problem. But I'm afraid your solution is not really a great one. Please read the Microsoft documentation on this subject.  E.g. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/).

Comment: Appsetting is only used temporarily. I intend on using a json file. The question is more about the type conversions and casting.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
List<TestDatum> testData = configuration.GetSection("testData")
                                        .Get<List<TestDatum>>();

public class TestDatum
{
    public string target { get; set; }
    public List<MockDatum> mockData { get; set; }
}

public class Contest
{
    public string contestKey { get; set; }
    public string contestType { get; set; }
    public string contestStatus { get; set; }
}

public class MockDatum
{
    public Request request { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public List<string> contestKeys { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Contest> contests { get; set; }
}
```